# Cloud machines available for free docker test

Tags: docker, testing, cloud, free

Can you please advise some cloud  machines available for free docker tests in learning purposes?

Answer (score -1):

https://training.play-with-docker.com/ is a good start. The tutorial will provide "cloud machine" for the training.

You can use also a free tier from standard cloud providers (AWS, GCP, ...), but it will require knowledge how to provision "cloud machine" there.